# Shell variable is not working

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to launch a program through a variable and it reads `run.sh` fine but it runs into issues when trying to launch the `.jar` file.

Normal running `run.sh` works fine and it launches the program as you can see below.

What is the problem?

```bsh
:~$ HAVEN=Desktop/Haven/run.sh
:~$ echo $HAVEN
Desktop/Haven/run.sh
:~$ $HAVEN
Error: Unable to access jarfile hafen.jar
:~$ cd Desktop/Haven
:~/Desktop/Haven$ ./run.sh
:~/Desktop/Haven$
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the script, `run.sh`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like `run.sh` is using relative paths. Your current working directory when you run it from `~/` is `~/` *not* `~/Desktop/Haven`.

You can fix this by `cd`ing to the directory of the script somewhere near the beginning of `run.sh`, with something like this:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")"
```

That, or you could have it specify the full paths to your jars.

Comment: Thanks. Your first sentence helped me fix the problem. I changed hafen.jar to Desktop/Haven/hafen.jar

Answer (score 0):

In case any variable is not working you can specify binary path of the command.

like.. If you use cp command and it does not work you can mention /bin/cp (Binary file for this command). In the same fashion you can use in you case as per the requirement.